# How to use NodeJSScript in Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: node.js, jenkins

When given npm install  in the Script window of Execute NodeJS window ( screenshot ) it doesnt run anything. any idea why this script is for ?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AeKvB.png)

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QSCms.png)

First configure nodejs. Settings -> Global Tool Configuration. Then go to job config. Check `Provide Node & npm bin/ folder to PATH`. After that, you choose execute shell from Build. Then write `write test.js` etc..,